# #Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: django-models, django-forms

In admin.py i have registered my models and when i am trying to add the data manually from
django admin panel by its inbuilt form (add) . The error came: Select a valid choice. That
choice is not one of the available choices. for both customer and role field . Please advise
if some one knows anything.

```
class UserRoles(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
     role_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.role_name} (Level {self.role_level})"

  class User(models.Model):
     _id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
      username = models.CharField(max_length=100)

      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.email) + ' | ' + str(self._id)

  class UserRoleMap(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    role = models.ForeignKey(
    UserRoles, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_role_id') : main problem
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
    User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_id') : main problem


    def __str__(self):
         return f"User: {self.customer.email}
```

Comment: Please a screenshot with your selected values before the error

Comment: i have found the solution the problem lies in ObjectId field . in payload we are sending string but in database is is saving as a object id so we need to edit the form and say django when post request convert those fields to objectid: